# Where my PostgreSQL database backup is stored after run pg_dump?

Tags: linux, postgresql

Login as a pgsql user

Typed the following command:

```
$ su - pgsql
```

Get list of database(s) to backup:

```
$ psql -l
```

I choosed users database

Type the following command

```
$ pg_dump users > users.dump.out
```

ok right, where I can find the users.dump.out ? , I need use that backup in other server.

Comment: That file (`users.dump.out`) should be in your current directory. Are you saying it isn't?

Answer (score 5):

`su -pgsql` changes the user to `pgsql` AND changes the current working directory (cwd) to pgsql's home directory.

You then ran the `pg_dump` command in `~pgsql/`, so the file you are looking for will be in that directory: `~pgsql/users.dump.out`

Answer (score 4):

I found the database backup, in my case was in:  /var/lib/postgresql#

Thanks all for the help.

Answer (score 2):

`users.dump.out` is in the directory, where you ran the command.

You can also use the `--file=` option to specify the output file.

Comment: I did run the command inside my www folder , but that file is not there :(

Comment: @user964836 you can try `find / -name 'users.dump.out'` to attempt to locate it. (Note that may take a while, depending on how many files you have, if you have mounted network shares, etc.)

Comment: no, you ran the `pg_dump` command in user pgsql's home directory (why? because `su - pgsql` not only changed the uid to pgsql, it changes the cwd to pgsql's home dir).  The file will be in `~pgsql/users.dump.out`

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu, try this

```
sudo su - postgres
pg_dump db_name > db_name.bak
```

and find backup in `/var/lib/postgresql`